# iTunes 12 didn't read id3 tags on Windows

Tags: itunes, music, mp3

My Hard drive and backup image drive died at the same time.
My Music was all stored on a third HD (Thank goodness) but I lost the itunes Database.
I've re-installed with iTunes 12.2.1.16 With Windows 7.
My issue at this point is that the files have the correct ID3 tags (Album, Artist, song title, but the file title might be: 03 song.mp3
Dragging the mp3 into itunes shows the file as '03 song' with no artist or album.

How can I force iTunes to read the id3 tag that is there in the file so I don;t have to go in and manually fix all the files that are wrong? (We're talking hundreds)